# Can we bundle more than one jenkins plugin into single installable jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins

I  have 10-15 required plugins to be installed in jenkins instance.
To avoid confusion and process of a installing all, I want to bundle all the hpi files into single hpi file and then install only once so that all the plugins will be installed at a time in a jenkins instance .

In there any way or process to do it in jenkins ?

Thanks & Regards,
Jagadish

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have used a very lay man approach where , I have made a script which will download all the hpi's from different location and copy into jenkins plugin directory and then restart the jenkins instance. It works but the solution seems to be very hooky. I need a clean approach/idea. If anybody have any idea for this problem statement then let me know

Comment: Some idea where I can bundle all hpi's into a single hpi ?